# Outlook synchronize feature extremely slow

Tags: performance, microsoft-outlook-2013

My Outlook synchronization function takes a very long time (>5 minutes). This delays features to the point of rendering Outlook not useful:

- New mail not pulled from server
- Search functionality hangs
- Sent mail doesn't leave outbox

Can someone explain to me why this is as a google search does not much help.

Comment: What are you synchronizing with?

Comment: @fixer1234 Godaddy imap server

Comment: The problem could be at their end.  I would wait 12 or 24 hours and then try again unless the problem has already been going on for a day or two.

Comment: @fixer1234 the problem has existed for 1+ months

Comment: It might be diagnostic to see what happens if you use POP3 if that's an option.

Comment: You are unable to send e-mail or it just takes a long time?

Answer (score 2):

Search functionality should not hang if you are running in Cached Exchange Mode.

In Outlook 2013:

- Go To File
- Account Settings > Account Settings
- Email Tab click on Change
- Check on Use Cached Exchange Mode.
- Move arrow all the way over to right to **All**
- Click Next, Click Finish

As long as you have Windows Search service installed and running, your e-mail searches will be local and very fast. It will never be Google fast, but still faster than what you've been experiencing.

[image: Account Settings]

[image: Cached Exchange Mode]

To Check if you have Windows Search, you can either run services.msc to see if Windows Search is running... Or check the indexing status in Outlook by Clicking on the Inbox Search. Then going to Search Tools > Indexing Status

[image: Indexing]

If you a message that says xxxx remain to index, that is a good sign. If you just see a spinning circle without a message, then you do not have Windows Search installed, or there is a problem with your Office 2013 installation.

[image: 0 remain to index]